# When using a channel beyond capacity, does the lower limit of bit error probability grow linearly?

Tags: information-theory

The "Mutual Information" YouTube channel shows in the video ["The Most Important (and Surprising) Result from Information Theory" at 4:18](https://youtu.be/q-Bbxvxpqvw?t=258) and then confirms in [its comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-Bbxvxpqvw&lc=UgyIwjxoUD7qcV7bUXN4AaABAg.9vwLVWcPZPu9vwPqi0rCwz) that Shannon proved not only that you can get arbitrarily close to 0 bit error probability with rates not exceeding the channel's capacity, but also that the relation switches to linear growth with the excess in rate afterwards. Is it true? I've seen graphs suggesting the contrary.

If it is linear, is there an intuitive argument for it?

Comment: I doubt it, see eg https://homepages.cwi.nl/~schaffne/courses/infcom/2014/reports/Report_Lucas_Slot_Sebastian_Zur.pdf
Anyway, the video is nice.

Comment: Actually, I looked at the video, and they're specifically talking about bit error rates, while I'm talking about block error (i.e., the average probability that at bit is incorrect v/s the probability that any bit is incorrect). So, the answer I posted might be irrelevant, although I still very much doubt the linear growth, and certainly the stuf fin the answer has some relation. I'd suggest some more reading on this: strong converse, channel dispersion, and error exponents should be reasonable keywords. Let me know if you find a good reference!

Answer (score 3):

Discrete memoryless channels (well, even finite-memory channels) were shown to admit "strong converses" by Wolfowitz back in the late 50s. These results are of the following form: let a $(n,M,\varepsilon)$ code be one that transmits $M$ messages over $n$ uses of the channel, with probability of error at most $\varepsilon$. Let $C$ be the capacity of the channel. Wolfowitz shows (for DMCs, say), that for any $\varepsilon < 1,$ if the probability of incorrect block decoding is $\le \varepsilon,$ then $M < 2^{nC + K\sqrt{n}}$ for some constant $K$. Note that the rate of the code in this notation is $\log M /n$.

In other words, if we send $n \to \infty$ (large blocklengths, which note that we *need* to communicate at rates close to capacity), then if the rate of the codebook exceeds capacity by any constant, the error rate *must* explode all the way to $1$. In fact even more is known: with finite blocklength, it turns out that to reliably communicate, we need to undershoot capacity in the sense that the highest $M$ achievable looks like $2^{nC - \sqrt{nV}Q^{-1}(\varepsilon) + O(\log n)},$ where $V$ is called channel dispersion, and $Q(x) = \int_x^\infty e^{-u^2/2}\mathrm{d}u/\sqrt{2\pi}$ is the Gaussian upper tail (so $Q^{-1}(\varepsilon) \sim \sqrt{2\log \varepsilon}$).